# How to split the entire string into array in Perl

Tags: arrays, string, perl

I'm trying to process an entire string but the way my code is written, part of it is not being processed. Here's a representation of my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $string = "MAGRSHPGPLRPLLPLLVVAACVLPGAGGTCPERALERREEEAN
              VVLTGTVEEILNVDPVQHTYSCKVRVWRYLKGKDLVARESLLDGGNKVVISGFGDPLI
              CDNQVSTGDTRIFFVNPAPPYLWPAHKNELMLNSSLMRITLRNLEEVEFCVEDKPGTH
              LRDVVVGRHPLHLLEDAVTKPELRPCPTP";

$string =~ s/\s+//g;     # remove white space from string
# split the string into fragments of 58 characters and store in array
my @array = $string =~ /[A-Z]{58}/g;   
my $len = scalar @array;
print $len . "\n";    # this prints 3
# print the fragments
print $array[0] . "\n";
print $array[1] . "\n";
print $array[2] . "\n";
print $array[3] . "\n";
```

The code outputs the following:

```
3
MAGRSHPGPLRPLLPLLVVAACVLPGAGGTCPERALERREEEANVVLTGTVEEILNVD
PVQHTYSCKVRVWRYLKGKDLVARESLLDGGNKVVISGFGDPLICDNQVSTGDTRIFF
VNPAPPYLWPAHKNELMLNSSLMRITLRNLEEVEFCVEDKPGTHLRDVVVGRHPLHLL
<blank space>
```

Notice that the rest of the string `EDAVTKPELRPCPTP` is not stored in `@array`. When I'm creating my array, how do I store `EDAVTKPELRPCPTP`? Perhaps I could store it in `$array[3]`?

Comment: Please don't name your variables something like `@array`. The `@` says that it's an array; the letters are supposed to convey something useful about the purpose of its contents

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've almost got it. You need to change your regex to allow for 1 to 58 characters.

```
my @array = $string =~ /[A-Z]{1,58}/g;
```

---

In addition, you have an error in your script using `@prot_seq` instead of `@array`. You should always `use strict` to protect yourself against this sort of thing. Here's the script with strict, warnings, and 5.10 features (to get [say](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/say.html)).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;

my $string = "MAGRSHPGPLRPLLPLLVVAACVLPGAGGTCPERALERREEEAN
              VVLTGTVEEILNVDPVQHTYSCKVRVWRYLKGKDLVARESLLDGGNKVVISGFGDPLI
              CDNQVSTGDTRIFFVNPAPPYLWPAHKNELMLNSSLMRITLRNLEEVEFCVEDKPGTH
              LRDVVVGRHPLHLLEDAVTKPELRPCPTP";

# Strip whitespace.
$string =~ s/\s+//g;

# Split the string into fragments of 58 characters or less
my @fragments = $string =~ /[A-Z]{1,58}/g;

say "Num fragments: ".scalar @fragments;
say join "\n", @fragments;
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're missing is the ability to capture *less* than 58 characters. And since you only want to do that if it's the end, you can do this:

```
/[A-Z]{58}|[A-Z]{1,57}\z/
```

Which I would prefer to write like this:

```
/\p{Upper}{58}|\p{Upper}{1,57}\z/
```

However, since this expression is *greedy* by default, it will prefer to gather 58 characters, and only default to less when it runs out of matching input.

```
/\p{Upper}{1,58}/
```

Or, for reasons as Schwern mentions (such as avoiding any foreign letters)

```
/[A-Z]{1,58}/
```

Comment: This is a case where I would recommend *against* using POSIX character classes. They're great when you're parsing language and want to make sure you're correctly internationalized. However, the encoding is likely specifically the ASCII characters A to Z. You *don't* want to pick up things like Ñ or ´E.

Comment: @Schwern: Those aren't POSIX character classes, they're Unicode properties

Comment: @Borodin Technically correct! Don't use either of them here.

Comment: @Schwern: Although I'm not certain of the difference between `\p{Upper}` and `\p{Lu}`. And it's worth noting that Perl 5.14 and better has the `/a` modifer, so `/\p{Lu}/a` is the same as `/[A-Z]/`; I'm not sure which I prefer

Comment: @Borodin I would very much prefer seeing the very straightforward `[A-Z]` vs having to go look up what `\p{Lu}` and `/a` do and requiring 5.14. `/a` is nice to know about though.

Answer (score 2):

You may prefer to use `unpack`, like this

```
$string =~ s/\s+//g;    
my @fragments = unpack '(A58)*', $string;
```

Or if you would rather leave `$string` unchanged and have v5.14 or better of Perl, then you can write

```
my @fragments = unpack '(A58)*', $string =~ s/\s+//gr;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't actually need regex character classes, this is how I'd do it:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dump;

my $string = "MAGRSHPGPLRPLLPLLVVAACVLPGAGGTCPERALERREEEAN
              VVLTGTVEEILNVDPVQHTYSCKVRVWRYLKGKDLVARESLLDGGNKVVISGFGDPLI
              CDNQVSTGDTRIFFVNPAPPYLWPAHKNELMLNSSLMRITLRNLEEVEFCVEDKPGTH
              LRDVVVGRHPLHLLEDAVTKPELRPCPTP";

$string =~ s/\s+//g;

my @chunks;

while (length($string)) {
    push(@chunks, substr($string, 0, 58, ''));
}

dd($string, \@chunks);
```

Output:

```
(
  "",
  [
    "MAGRSHPGPLRPLLPLLVVAACVLPGAGGTCPERALERREEEANVVLTGTVEEILNVD",
    "PVQHTYSCKVRVWRYLKGKDLVARESLLDGGNKVVISGFGDPLICDNQVSTGDTRIFF",
    "VNPAPPYLWPAHKNELMLNSSLMRITLRNLEEVEFCVEDKPGTHLRDVVVGRHPLHLL",
    "EDAVTKPELRPCPTP",
  ],
)
```

Comment: This answer assumes the data is entirely made of `A-Z`. It's also destructive.

Comment: Both of which are valid assumptions, I think, given the sample input and the fact that the original question was _already_ modifying `$string`.